# Can I find the most popular keyword for a particular page using the google analytics api?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I was hoping to to use the analytics api to find out the most popular search terms (organic) that lead to a particular page.

Is this possible?

I've trawled the documentation and found this which looks as if it outlines all possible data I can retrieve from the API and I can't see this information here.

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDimensionsMetrics.html

If this is the case, is there any reason that the API isn't complete? I would assume if I can access the data using the analytics interface then I should be able to query for it using the API - is this assumption incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. For example, if you wanted to see what keywords led to how many entrances to index.html,

Set:

**Dimensions**: ga:keyword

**Metrics**: ga:entrances

**Segment**: gaid::-5

**Filters**: ga:landingPagePath==/index.html

**Sort**: -ga:entrances

(Segment gaid::-5 segments the data to only include visits referred from Organic Search; sorting by -ga:entrances will order the number of visits in descending order).

Try it out here: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html?dimensions=ga%253Akeyword&metrics=ga%253Aentrances&segment=gaid%253A%253A-5&filters=ga%253AlandingPagePath%253D%253D%252Findex.html&sort=-ga%253Aentrances&start-date=2010-09-23&end-date=2010-10-07&max-results=50

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I guess I thought that because the documentation for ga:keyword was under the Campaigns section - it could only be used for adwords campaigns.

Comment: @calumbrodie yeah, its a common confusion, but all of the variables in the Campaign section that don't begin with 'Ad' are available for non-Adwords info.